# Marking points that are above limit with marker at ylimit (matplotlib plot_date)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a graph that gets redrawn every minute with all of the measurements so far during the night. I'm plotting by an amount of loss of magnitude so the y axis is plotted reverse, with zero at top and whatever you want at the bottom. Occasionally we'll get points larger than my bottom ylim of 1.4 while it's not really important that they're larger (because looking for detail between limits), it is important to mark that there was a measurement taken and that it was off of the scale.

Is there an easy way in matplot lib that takes points beyond the ylimit and just points them at/on the ylimit line? What suggestions might you have?

```
ax.set_ylim(bottom=1.4,top=0,emit=True,auto=False)    
ax.plot_date(x, y, 'black', marker='o', fillstyle='full', ms=7 , ls='none', zorder=10)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would just `np.clip` the y values.  If you want to be fancy, you could also color those values differently w/ another call to `plot_date`.

Comment: use numpy.where: `y_to_plot = numpy.where(y >= threshold, threshold, y)`